# Using await with an event implementing CancelEventArgs

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have a base class similar to this:

```
public abstract class PageBase
{
    public PageBase() { }

    public Task<object> Refresh(ModelRequirements requirements)
    {
        // does work of talking to server and getting data
    }

    private DataStates _dataState;
    public DataStates DataState()
    {
        get { _dataState = value; }

        set
        {
            var e = new DataStateChangingEventArgs();

            // the following method raises the changing event.
            // it does not return a task, and cannot be awaited.
            OnDataStateChanging(e);

            if (e.Cancel)
                return;

            _dataState = value;
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<DataStateChangingEventArgs> DataStateChanging;
    protected virtual void OnDataStateChanging(DataStateChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataStateChanging = DataStateChanging;
        if (DataStateChanging != null)
            DataStateChanging(this, e);
    }
}
```

And I implement a page like this:

```
public class ContactsSearchPage : PageBase
{
    public ContactsSearchPage() { }

    private ContactModel Model {get; set;}

    protected async override void OnDataStateChanging(DataStateChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        // make new requirements
        var contactRequirements = new ContactRequirements();

        // Because the Refresh is awaited, it returns here and the rest 
        // of the DataState setter executes
        var refreshResult = await Refresh(contactRequirements);

        // set the property
        Model = refreshResult as ContactModel;

        // if the server returned null don't allow the data-state change to proceed
        if (Model == null)
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Awaiting on the refresh (inside the OnDataStateChanging override) is a problem since it returns. Without making OnDataStateChanging return Task, is there a solution to this pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an expectation that a property setter will *actually set the property*, and that it will do so before the setter returns.  Violating this expectation will cause confusion.

> is there a solution to this pattern?

I would recommend changing your property into a getter, and a method to handle the set:

```
public DataStates DataState { get; private set; }

public Task UpdateDataStateAsync()
{
   // ... Use await as necessary
```

This will make your API match what's actually occurring internally, and be far more understandable.